# Transfer Image throug BLE in android

Tags: android, image, bluetooth-lowenergy, transfer

I'm transfering an image of 1 mb using the following code.
The image gets transferred successfully if a thread delay is implemented between each packets.
If the thread delay is not set all the packets are sent from BluetoothGattServer but the BluetoothGattCallback does not receive all the packets.

Can anyone guide in sending the packets without the thread delay

Implement thread between each packets

```
private void sendingContinuePacket(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                   byte[] CHARACTERS) {
    boolean isComplete = false;
    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        tv_status.setText("Sending Data...!!");
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
    });

    // Check the data length is large how many times with Default Data (BLE)

    int times = CHARACTERS.length / DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET;
    totalPackets = times;
    Log.i("", "CHARACTERS.length() " + CHARACTERS.length);

    byte[] packetNoByte;
    byte[] sending_continue_hex = new byte[DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET];
    for (int time = 0; time <= times; time++) {

        final int remainingTime = time;
        if (!hasDisconnected) {
            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if (totalPackets != 0) {
                        showProgress(totalPackets, remainingTime);
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                tv_progress.setText(0 + "%");
                tv_timer.setText("00:00:00");
                tv_imageSize.setText("");
                tv_status.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(PeripheralRoleActivity.this, "Something went wrong, Please Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            });
            return;
        }
        int a;
        int b;

        /**
         * @param THREAD_SLEEP_TIME_FOR_NOTIFICATION
         * this delay is placed to give a small pause while sending the data packe
         * */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Constants.THREAD_SLEEP_TIME_FOR_NOTIFICATION);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sentPacket = sentPacket + 1;
        byte[] packetArray = Utils.getUtilsClass().toByteArray(sentPacket);
        packetNoByte = Arrays.copyOf(packetArray, packetArray.length);

        if (time == times) {
            Log.i("", "LAST PACKET ");
            int character_length = CHARACTERS.length
                    - DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET * times;
            byte[] sending_last_hex = new byte[character_length];
            a = (sending_continue_hex.length) * time;
            b = a + character_length;
            if(b-a ==0){
                return;
            }
            sending_last_hex = Arrays.copyOfRange(CHARACTERS, a, b);

            byte[] last_packet =
                    new byte[packetNoByte.length + character_length];
            System.arraycopy(packetNoByte, 0, last_packet,
                    0, packetNoByte.length);
            System.arraycopy(sending_last_hex, 0, last_packet,
                    packetNoByte.length, sending_last_hex.length);


            Log.d("Sending packets", Arrays.toString(last_packet));
            // Set value for characteristic
            characteristic.setValue(last_packet);
            notifyCharacteristicChanged();
            isComplete = true;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
            currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            Log.d("Collection", "End Time: " + currentDateTimeString);
            Utils.getUtilsClass().sendNotification(getApplicationContext(), "Data Transfer", "Transfer Complete");


        } else {

            Log.i("", "CONTINUE PACKET ");

            a = ((sending_continue_hex.length) * time);
            b = a + DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET;

            sending_continue_hex = Arrays.copyOfRange(CHARACTERS, a, b);


            byte[] sending_continue_packet =
                    new byte[packetNoByte.length + sending_continue_hex.length];
            System.arraycopy(packetNoByte, 0, sending_continue_packet,
                    0, packetNoByte.length);
            System.arraycopy(sending_continue_hex, 0, sending_continue_packet,
                    packetNoByte.length, sending_continue_hex.length);


            Log.d("data transfer a", String.valueOf(a));
            Log.d("data transfer b", String.valueOf(b));
            Log.d("data trans bytes", String.valueOf(sending_continue_hex.length));
            if(output == null){
                output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            }
            try {
                if {
                    characteristic.setValue(sending_continue_packet);
                    Log.d("Sending packets", Arrays.toString(sending_continue_packet));
                    notifyCharacteristicChanged();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        Log.d("Data byte", "times " + time);

        if (isComplete) {
            characteristic.setValue("Completed");
            notifyCharacteristicChanged();
        }
        runOnUiThread(() -> tv_status.setText("Data sent!!"));
    }
}
```

**Updated Code**

//the following function is used break the image byte [] into packets and store it in an arraylist

```
private void breakPackets(byte[] CHARACTERS) {
        // Check the data length is large how many times with Default Data (BLE)

        int times = CHARACTERS.length / DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET;
        totalPackets = times;
        packetList = new ArrayList<>();
        sendingPacket = 0;
        Log.i("", "CHARACTERS.length() " + CHARACTERS.length);


        byte[] sending_continue_hex = new byte[DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET];
        for (int time = 0; time <= times; time++) {


            int a;
            int b;

            if (time == times) {
                Log.i("", "LAST PACKET ");
                int character_length = CHARACTERS.length
                        - DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET * times;
                byte[] sending_last_hex = new byte[character_length];
                a = (sending_continue_hex.length) * time;
                b = a + character_length;

                sending_last_hex = Arrays.copyOfRange(CHARACTERS, a, b);
                //packetList is an ArrayList<byte[]>
                packetList.add(sending_last_hex);
                startSendingPackets(sendingPacket);
            } else {
                a = (sending_continue_hex.length) * time;
                b = a + DEFAULT_BYTES_IN_CONTINUE_PACKET;
                sending_continue_hex = Arrays.copyOfRange(CHARACTERS, a, b);

                packetList.add(sending_continue_hex);
            }
            Log.d("Data byte", "times " + time);

        }
    }

    //the following function is used to set the byte[] from the arraylist to the characteristics and then notify the characteristics
     private void startSendingPackets(int packet) {
        isCommand = false;
        mSampleCharacteristic.setValue(packetList.get(packet));
        notifyCharacteristicChanged();
        Log.i("packeting", "Sending  ------------> " + packet);
    }


    /*************************************************/



     @Override
        public void onNotificationSent(BluetoothDevice device, int status) {
            super.onNotificationSent(device, status);
            //check if status is success
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            //if status is not successful isExecutable is false and the else loop is executed to resend the same packet that has failed
                if (isExecutable) {
//                    Log.i("packeting", "Sent  ------------> " + sendingPacket);
                    sendingPacket = sendingPacket + 1;
                    int size = packetList.size();
                    if (sendingPacket <= size-1) {

                        startSendingPackets(sendingPacket);

                        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Notification sent. Status: " + status + " sending packet no --" + sendingPacket);
                    } else {
                        sendCommand("Completed");
                    }
                } else {
                    startSendingPackets(sendingPacket);
                    isExecutable = true;
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Notification sent. Status: " + status + " sending packet no --" + sendingPacket);
                }
            }else{
            //if status is not successful
                isExecutable = false;

                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Notification sent. fail Status: " + status );
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be read in the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServerCallback.html#onNotificationSent(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice,%20int):

> When multiple notifications are to be sent, an application must wait
>   for this callback to be received before sending additional
>   notifications.

This means after you have called `notifyCharacteristicChanged`, you cannot call `notifyCharacteristicChanged` again until the callback `onNotificationSent` has been received. So you need to remove your `for`-loop and refactor your code to follow the API rules.

The reason for this is to get flow control. If you just push new packets faster than the BLE link's throughput, the internal buffers get full and packet loss will occur. That's why a delay might seem to work, but it's not a robust solution so that's why you should wait for the `onNotificationSent` callback since that means the BLE stack is ready to accept new packets.

Comment: Hi Emil, thanks for your reply, I have updated my code as per your suggestion. Can you please confirm the flow , so that I'm in the right path.

Comment: @jennifersashi Please don't modify the code after you have received an answer. This is not how StackOverflow works. Now your question and the answer no longer match. StackOverflow is a knowledge base. Questions and answers should also serve many future visitors. Take your discussion about the changed code somewhere else.

Comment: As of now I'm sending the packets based on the onNotificationSent callback, each packet hold 509 bytes ( in BLE 5.0 version) and the number of packets is ~2030. While sending these packets in the range of 230 to 260th packet , I'm getting status as 129 so I resend the same packet. What is the cause for status 129?